# How do you connect to a network that IS broadcasting but DOES NOT have an SSID?

Tags: wireless, security

I have access to the MAC address and signal strength. He's not jamming my network, but he is bridging my wireless network. I want to connect to his network and figure out what he's doing. Any advice or resources will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use unprintable characters in a SSID (it supports UTF-8) and a 32-byte string of NULL-bytes is a valid SSID (that would be an invisible SSID).

Comment: Ok, I'm off to google to get a utf unprintable range!

Answer (score 2):

Kismet can be used to capture and dump the raw wifi traffic, including the SSID. You can then parse the data dump through your favorite language using an available PCAP library. You could then convert the SSID to something more human friendly like hex, octal, or ASCII code values OR you could exec() iwconfig from there. An example in Perl of [parsing via PCAP](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=450805).

I was going to leave this second part in a comment to the original question, but I do not have enough rep: You might have better luck in finding out what the intruder is doing by monitoring the traffic on your own network that is coming across the bridge.